# Wanting to use watchPath with file attribute manipulations

Tags: nextflow

I am trying to use watchPath in nextflow to look for a file type, and then get the file attributes. Something like:

```
Channel.watchPath("/path/to/a/*/ready.txt", 'create' ).view()
                        .map{row ->
                        def readyPath = file(row[0])
                        def path2move = readyPath.getParent()
                        def TNname    = path2move.getBaseName()
                        [TNname, path2move ]
                        }.view().set{TNReadyFiles}
```

In my final view statement I keep getting "to" and "/path/to", rather than "/path/to/a/dir/" (directory wherever the file gets created). "path/to" happens to be the directory of my script and working directory. how can i get accurate file manipulations after using watchpath?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
Channel.watchPath("/path/to/a/*/ready.txt", 'create' ).view()
                        .map{row ->
                        def readyPath = row.getParent()
                        def TNname    = row.getName()
                        [TNname, readyPath ]
                        }.view().set{TNReadyFiles}
```

https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/script.html#check-file-attributes

Comment: you did! my issue was using row[0] instead of row.